Agregar estilo en <a </a>
necesito cambiar el estilo para que el texto sea más pequeño. El código es el siguiente:
<a href="https://sitio.com" data-ajax="?link1=timeline&amp;u=Comprar"> <b>Comprar</b> </a>

Cuando consulto el css, veo que a ya tiene estilo, pero si lo modifico no solo modifica el texto Compras, también afecta todo lo que esté entre <a  .
Como puedo hacer para cambiar el estilo si ya tiene uno con a

aplicale una class, o aplicale solo el estilo a ese componente...

Literalmente en esa Ancla solo existe la palabra Comprar que otra cosa se supone que cambie?? Y como ya te dijeron, ponle una etiqueta a Comprar dentro del Ancla y listo. Esa tag <b> te puede funcionar también.

Agrégale un estilo al elemento a y dentro de ese estilo puedes agregar el css que tu quieras separado con ; o incluye el css en su propio archivo y usa una clase.
Por ejemplo:


.small-font {
  font-size: 12px;
}
Original:

<a href="https://sitio.com" data-ajax="?link1=timeline&amp;u=Comprar"> <b>Comprar</b> </a>
</br>

Usando estilo en el elemento:

<a style="font-size: 12px;" href="https://sitio.com" data-ajax="?link1=timeline&amp;u=Comprar"> <b>Comprar</b> </a>
</br>

Usando una clase:
<a class="small-font" href="https://sitio.com" data-ajax="?link1=timeline&amp;u=Comprar"> <b>Comprar</b> </a>




Muchas gracias a ambos por la ayuda, lo hice y me quedo super bien :)

Que bueno que funciono. Acuerdate de aceptar la respuesta.
